# Visual Studio/.NET: Added Java-based web service reference using wsdl but can't find it

Tags: java, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to add a java-based web service reference to my .NET project using a WSDL generated by it, but every time I have added it, I cannot find it from the code, let alone invoke its one webmethod.

I can add it alright, and it shows up in my project tree, but I cannot see the methods and I cannot find or access the webservice from my code. When I right click it and try to view it in the object browser, it doesn't show up. What gives?

This is the contents of the wsdl (I left out the data types to keep it small):

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
        xmlns:tns="http://logiasoftware.fi/HandyManifestFargoOnRamp2010_01/" 
        targetNamespace="http://logiasoftware.fi/HandyManifestFargoOnRamp2010_01/">

      <wsdl:message name="Response">
          <wsdl:part name="DefaultInput" element="tns:Response"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="Request">
          <wsdl:part name="DefaultOutput" element="Request"/>
      </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="HandyManifestFargoOnRampServiceSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="SaveFCO">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:Request"/>
              <wsdl:output message="tns:Response"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="HandyManifestFargoOnRampServiceSoap" type="tns:HandyManifestFargoOnRampServiceSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaveFCO">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://logiasoftware.fi/HandyManifestFargoOnRampService/SaveFCO" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
              <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="GenericSoapFault">
                <soap:fault name="GenericSoapFault" use="literal"/>
                </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="HandyManifestFargoOnRampService">
        <wsdl:port name="HandyManifestFargoOnRampServiceSoap" binding="tns:HandyManifestFargoOnRampServiceSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://logiasoftware.fi/HandyManifestFargoOnRampService/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Trying to run the wsdl through svcutil.exe gives me some interesting error messages:

```
 R1014: The children of the soap:Body element in a ENVELOPE MUST be namespace qualified. The use of unqualified element names may cause naming conflicts, therefore qualified names must be used for the children of soap:Body.
   -  Part 'DefaultOutput' of message 'Request' from service description with targetNamespace='http://logiasoftware.fi/HandyManifestFargoOnRamp2010_01/'.
```

and...

```
 Error: Unable to import binding 'HandyManifestFargoOnRampServiceSoap' from namespace 'http://logiasoftware.fi/HandyManifestFargoOnRamp2010_01/'.
   - Unable to import operation 'SaveFCO'.
   - The element 'http://logiasoftware.fi/HandyManifestFargoOnRamp2010_01/:Response' is missing.
```

So this tells me that the message elements should have the same namespace specified (http://logiasoftware.fi/) in the sections below:

```
<wsdl:message name="Response">
    <wsdl:part name="DefaultInput" element="tns:Response"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Request">
    <wsdl:part name="DefaultOutput" element="Request"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

But how do I do that?

Comment: This looks to be an older question, but I'll ask this anyway...does the Java web service test fine?  i.e. - can you invoke the web service directly through a browser interface and/or does wget (http://www.gnu.org/software/wget) successfully retrieve the wsdl when you call it?

Comment: Which java webservice toolkit are you using?

Comment: Also try the webservice with SoapUI, a tool to test web services.

Comment: Hi guys, it was solved somehow a long time ago, but I can no longer recall what the solution was. Thanks for all your advice in any case!!

Comment: @prajeeshkumar I use SoapUI to test all soap based webservices when creatin a consuming application. +1 for mentioning SoapUI.

Comment: Do you see this service listed under your project's 'Service References' ?